# How to completely remove GoToMeeting.app?

Tags: macos, applications

I installed the [`GoToMeeting.app`](https://www.gotomeeting.com) because a client used it. I no longer need it, but I can't seem to remove it. Its burrowed in worse than most malware found on a PC.

I tried a simple drag and drop from the ***`Applications`*** folder to the ***`Trash`***, but that did not work.

I then dropped into the command line:

```
$ ls /Applications/Go*
/Applications/GoToMeeting:
GoToMeeting (3019).app  GoToMeeting (3356).app
GoToMeeting (3277).app  GoToMeeting (3499).app
$
```

Then:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /Applications/GoToMeeting*
$ ls /Applications/Go*
$
```

Finally, reboot and then:

```
$ ls /Applications/Go*
GoToMeeting (WWW).app  GoToMeeting (XXX).app
GoToMeeting (YYY).app  GoToMeeting (ZZZ).app
$
```

So I get another set of them.

Something is running in privileged mode, and it seems to be hiding itself:

```
$ sudo find /Library -iname GoToMeeting 2>/dev/null
$
$ sudo ps -A | grep -i GoToMeeting
13644 ttys000    0:00.00 grep -i GoToMeeting
$
```

The hit above is the terminal session searching for the process.

How do I completely remove this application?

Comment: Have a look at: [How do I uninstall GoToMeeting on my Mac?](http://support.citrixonline.com/en_US/meeting/knowledge_articles/000048860)

Comment: Thanks  user3439894. Based on the behavior I am seeing, I don't believe its a complete remediation. That is, I don't believe it will completely remove all the application components (otherwise, nuk'ing it from the command line would have worked). Where can I find a list of the malware included with their primary ***`GoToMeeting.app`***?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in your user library. Try this:

```
rm -fv ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.citrixonline.GoToMeeting.G2MUpdate.plist

rm -rfv ~/Library/Application\ Support/CitrixOnline/
```

Comment: Thanks. That appears to be it. How did GoToMeeting re-install itself into `/Applications`? That's protected and requires privileges, but I was never prompted with a `sudo`. (And its the reason all my `find`'s occurred in `/Library`, and not `~/Library`).

Comment: If your user is an admin, it has explicit write permissions for  /Applications/:

`drwxrwxr-x+ 79 root  admin  2686 Oct  2 20:17 Applications`

Since the launch agent runs as you, it write to /Applications/.

Comment: Since the program run by the launch agent runs as your user, it can also write to /Applications/

I can't English today.

Comment: *"Since the program run by the launch agent..."* - OK, this appear to be another related issue. I use [Loadables](http://vladalexa.com/apps/osx/loadables/) to track startup programs, but it never reported anything for my user account. Additionally, Apple's [Users & Groups](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18901?locale=en_US) settings applet did not report it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Loadables (although it looks useful), so I'm not sure why it didn't show up there. The items listed under Login Items in the Users and Groups prefpane are not launch agents. Those items are just entries in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist.